# Importing PDF into MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm sorry for the log post but I am about to pull my hair out. I am attempting to import a PDF into a database.

The main error I am getting is: "*Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(MAX) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query*."

Some of the coding included below is for a SEARCH function that is not yet completed. Please disregard that area of coding.

Basically I am loading a PDF in the AxAcroPDF1 box. This works great. It then pre-fills out a few of the textboxes. User inputs the Broker Load Number than hits save and a openfiledialog opens and the file is chosen to be imported. This then is where the failed import happens and the error above is given. I have tried many different avenues but always ending up with the same result. I am at a complete and total loss.

Table structure is as follows:

```
ID, int, NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BROKER_LOAD_NUMBER nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
PDF_FILENAME,nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
PETS_LOAD_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
PAPERWORK varbinary(MAX) NOT NULL
```

My FULL code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class LoadDocs
    Private DV As DataView
    Private currentRow As String

    Private Sub LoadDocs_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DocDataset.Documents_Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Documents_TableTableAdapter.Fill(DocDataset.Documents_Table)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOpenPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenPDF.Click
        Dim CurYear As String = CType(Now.Year(), String)

        On Error Resume Next
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        AxAcroPDF1.src = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        tbFilePath.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim filename As String = tbFilePath.Text.ToString
        tbFileName.Text = filename.Substring(Math.Max(0, filename.Length - 18))

        Dim loadnumber As String = tbFileName.Text
        tbPetsLoadNumber.Text = loadnumber.Substring(7, 7)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchResult()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        'SQL to get specific data from the Documents_Table
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        If cbColName.Text = "SEARCH BY:" Then
            MeMsgBoxSearchCriteria.ShowDialog()
        Else : lblSearchResults.Items.Clear()
            Select Case DocDataset.Documents_Table.Columns(cbColName.Text).DataType
                Case GetType(Integer)
                    DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = " & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim
                Case GetType(Date)
                    DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = #" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "#"
                Case Else
                    DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " LIKE '*" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "*'"
            End Select

            If DV.Count > 0 Then
                For IX As Integer = 0 To DV.Count - 1
                    lblSearchResults.Items.Add(DV.Item(IX)("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER"))
                Next
                If DV.Count = 1 Then
                    lblSearchResults.SelectedIndex = 0
                    Dim ix As Integer = DocumentsTableBindingSource.Find("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER", CInt(lblSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString))
                    DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position = ix
                Else
                    lblSearchResults.Visible = True
                    lblSearchResults.BringToFront()
                End If
            Else
                ' Display a message box notifying users the record cannot be found.   
                MeMsgBoxNoSearch.ShowDialog()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LbllSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSearchResults.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim ix As Integer = DocumentsTableBindingSource.Find("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER", CInt(lblSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString))
        DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position = ix
        lblSearchResults.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub DocumentsTableBindingSource_PositionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DocumentsTableBindingSource.PositionChanged
        Try
            currentRow = DocDataset.Documents_Table.Item(DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position).ToString

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSavePDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSavePDF.Click
        If tbPetsLoadNumber.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a PETS Load Number", "Missing Load Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf tbBrokerLoadNumber.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Broker Load Number", "Missing Load Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf tbFileName.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Filename", "Missing Filename", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            Using OpenFileDialog As OpenFileDialog = OpenFileDialog1()

                If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK) Then
                    tbFilePath.Text = OpenFileDialog.FileName

                Else 'Cancel
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            End Using

            'Call Upload Images Or File
            Dim sFileToUpload As String = ""

            sFileToUpload = LTrim(RTrim(tbFilePath.Text))

            Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(sFileToUpload)
            upLoadImageOrFile(sFileToUpload, "PDF")
            upLoadImageOrFile(sFileToUpload, Extension)

            'Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
            Dim data As Byte() = Nothing

            'Use FileInfo object to get file size.
            Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(tbFilePath.Text)
            Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length

            'Open FileStream to read file
            Dim fStream As New FileStream(tbFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            'Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)

            'Supply number of bytes to read from file.
            'In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
            data = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))

            'Insert the details into the database
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Documents_Table (BROKER_LOAD_NUMBER, PDF_FILENAME, PETS_LOAD_NUMBER, PAPERWORK)
                                    VALUES ('@bl', '@fn', '@pl', '@pdf');"

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", tbFileName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbPetsLoadNumber.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bl", tbBrokerLoadNumber.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fp", tbFilePath.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdf", data)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection With {
                .ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.PETS_DatabaseConnectionString
            }
            cmd.Connection.Open()

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.Connection.Close()

            MsgBox("File successfully Imported to Database")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub upLoadImageOrFile(sFilePath As String, sFileType As String)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim Data As Byte()
        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim qry As String

        Try
            'Read Image Bytes into a byte array

            Data = ReadFile(sFilePath)
            sFileName = Path.GetFileName(sFilePath)

            'Set insert query
            qry = "INSERT INTO Documents_Table (BROKER_LOAD_NUMBER, PDF_FILENAME, PETS_LOAD_NUMBER, PAPERWORK)
                                        VALUES ('@bl', '@fn', '@pl', '@pdf')"

            'Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cmd.Connection)

            'We are passing File Name and Image byte data as sql parameters.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", tbFileName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbPetsLoadNumber.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bl", tbBrokerLoadNumber.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fp", tbFilePath.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdf", Data)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("File uploaded successfully")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("File could not uploaded")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function ReadFile(sFilePath As String) As Byte()
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES ('@bl', '@fn', '@pl', '@pdf')` Try that _without_ the quotes.

Comment: The error message **literally** tells you what to do: _Use the [(MS SQL) CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to run this query._

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO Documents_Table (BROKER_LOAD_NUMBER, PDF_FILENAME, PETS_LOAD_NUMBER, PAPERWORK) VALUES (@bl, @fn, @pl, @pdf)"` and `cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdf", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = data`. Size = -1 is needed to exceed 8000 bytes; it maps to `varbinary(max)`. You should specify all of your data types instead of using `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Now I am getting a not declared error at line: Private Sub upLoadImageOrFile -  Data = ReadFile(sFilePath) - ReadFile is the item supposedly not declared. I'm not sure where this should be declared or if declaring it is actually required.

Comment: I also updated the code in the original posting to reflect changes as suggested by RUUD and @user9938

Comment: Are you sure that the database columns are `nvarchar` and not `varchar`?  If using [varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it's not necessary to specify the size.

Comment: You have a typo. In the SQL statement you have `@pl` (lower-case 'L') and in `cmd.Parameters.Add`, you have `@p1` (one).

Comment: "ReadFile is the item supposedly not declared." Well, it _was_ defined, until you edited the question and removed it from the class.

Comment: "I also updated the code in the original posting to reflect changes as suggested by RUUD and @user9938" I have rolled back your edit. You ask a _specific_ question, and we try to find an answer for that. You edit to improve the question; not to answer it. Feel free to post an _answer_ (maybe a comment put you on the right track), but do not patch the answer into your question. And to raise a new issue (regardless of whether it is in the same project or not), post a new question (_after_ making an honest attempt to solve it yourself, of course).

Comment: BINGO @user9938. Good catch. I missed that. Problem resolved for now. NOW I need to get the search function to work and my life will be happy!!